# retrieve and display data, from table stored in database, into a form (using foreign key).

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I have two tables, these are shown below:

Employee - (employee_ID, first_name, Last_name, Address, ETC)
Training - (training_ID, Employee_ID, First_name, Last_name, Training)

Employee ID is foreign key in training table.

I have a form for the training table, which is meant to be used by someone who will enter which employee needs which training.

Is there anyway on my training form, I can have a drop down box for the employee field which will automatically update the first name and last name for that employee ID?

OR is there just anyway I can have my form so that the employee ID is always with the right first name and last name.

here is my form (html) and php code to submit it to database.

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<title>Training</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">  
<h1 align="center">Add Training</h1>

<form action="inserttraining.php" method="post">
<div>
<p>Training ID: <input type="text" name="Training_ID"></p>
<p>Employee ID: <input type="text" name="Employee_ID"></p>
<p>First name: <input type="text" name="First_name"></p>
<p>Last name: <input type="text" name="Last_name"></p>
<p>
Training required?
<select name="Training">
<option value="">Select...</option>
<option value="Customer Service">Customer Service</option>
<option value="Bailer">Bailer</option>
<option value="Reception">Reception</option>
<option value="Fish & meat counters">Fish & meat counters</option>
  <option value="Cheese counters">Cheese counters</option>
</select>
</p>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and php code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("hrmwaitrose", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO training (Training_ID, Employee_ID, First_name, Last_name, Training)
VALUES
  ('$_POST[Training_ID]','$_POST[Employee_ID]','$_POST[First_name]','$_POST[Last_name]','$_POST[Training]')";


if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks in advance and sorry if my code doesnt display well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your text fields (Firstname, Lastname) using a dropdown you will need to use ajax.

Simply make an ajax request using the onChange event of the dropdown and set the returned  values to text fields using javascript.

For pre-populated values you can do following:

```
//code to get data from database

//store the result in an array
$result = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

//change the html in your form
<p>First name: <input type="text" name="First_name" value="<?php if(!empty($result['First_name'])) echo $result['First_name']; ?>"></p>
<p>Last name: <input type="text" name="Last_name" value="<?php if(!empty($result['last_name'])) echo $result['last_name']; ?>"></p>
```

Comment: thank you for your help, ALTHOUGH I don't know how to have a drop down box containing the employee ID values from the employee table. is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Read the tutorial on the link... http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/051e29/dropdown-list-in-php/